MOSFET Breakdown Voltage for this BMS circuit
I'm trying to design a BMS which has the following characteristics:

20 lithium-ion cells
in the discharging state, the cells are connected in series to develop a voltage of 84V max
in the charging state, the cells are connected in parallel
if any cell disconnects from its current state network (in case of overdischarge of overcharge), other cells must still be allowed to function.
in case of overdischarge in particular, the cell switches its low-side MOSFET off and current is rerouted through a diode which bypasses the cell, which makes the total voltage suddenly drop by 4 volts; I'm ok with that.
I'd like to discharge the cells at up to 10A, which complicates MOSFET/diode selection even more.

Here is the discharging section of my schematic :

Notes:

Here is a link to this schematic in falstad
Both sections can be seen on this similar one-cell schematic where C- and C+ are the parallel charging inputs and P+ and P- are series discharging outputs.
The switches at the MOSFETs gates would be microcontroller outputs in a final product. I'm aware that this will make my MOSFETs turn on rather slowly due to the low provided current. They will always be turned on before any load would be attached to the BMS, so I feel like it's not a problem.
This schematic show only 3 cells whereas the final product would have 20 cells.

Now my question is about the MOSFET component selection.
I figured the breakdown voltage should be above 84V, as this is what I think could be measured across drain-source of each MOSFET. Is this correct or am I missing something?
I'm a bit confused because I don't see any breakdown voltage in the datasheet of the (very common) lithium cells I'm planning to use: should I be concerned about stacking so many of them?
I should probably say that I'm not a professional electronician, all I know was learned online.

Batteries don't have a "breakdown" voltage like you seem to think. EVs have them in series going up to the 800V sort of range.

@Finbarr breakdown voltage of the cell sleeve is a legitimate concern, EVs avoid this by grouping them in e.g. 20..50V packs with additional isolation.

What I really wonder is how the parallel/series switchover will be done and why?

@fraxinus As shown in the second schematic, it takes three more MOSFETs per cell

@fraxinus as for "why", it seems to me like an easier way to do balanced charging and it allows charging with a rather low voltage.

well... the whole idea to be able to kick a cell out sounds reasonable if you are dealing with large, but very low quality or salvaged cells and you are ok with the discharge current passing 20 fets instead of 2 (and the power loss and the heat implied).

charging, on the other hand, will require low voltage, very high current source and insanely big conductors. And more loss and heat. And good luck equalizing the voltage drops across them in order to get balanced anything.

@fraxinus I have no charging speed requirement and so was thinking to charge them with as little as 200mA, requiring 4A in total.

It could be made to work, sure. Still, how big are your cells?

@fraxinus 18650 cells, 2000 to 3000mAh
